# Is there any way to erase the countries and cities names from mapview?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I'm looking for way to display the google map without countries or city names.
I'm using the android.maps.MapView to display the maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text labels are built into the data from Google and there is unfortunately no way to remove them.

The [Google Maps v2 framework](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#map_types) lets you display satellite data without text labels.